# runtime error with worksheet copy in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, worksheet-function

getting a runtime error, specifically copying the worksheet.  It used to work but not sure what I am missing here.  I am using v16.0, and single workbook.  Here is the portion of the code:

```
Private Sub btnNewExchange_Click()
Worksheets("Exchange Master").Copy After:=Worksheets("Exchange Master")

'Copy the coefficients and freeze them into the current sheet

Worksheets("Exchange Master (2)").Unprotect
Worksheets("Exchange Master (2)").Range("D7:D18").Value = Worksheets("Exchange Master").Range("D7:D18").Value
Worksheets("Exchange Master (2)").Protect

' Rename the sheet
Worksheets("Exchange Master (2)").Select
Worksheets("Exchange Master (2)").Name = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") & " Exchange"

UserForm1.Hide
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Might help to be more explicit about the objects you're working with.

If you still get an error then it would help to include the text of the error in your question.

```vb
Private Sub btnNewExchange_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    'best to be explicit about the workbook you're working on
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook?
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Exchange Master")

    ws.Copy After:=ws

    With wb.Worksheets(ws.Index + 1)
        .Unprotect
        .Range("D7:D18").Value = ws.Range("D7:D18").Value
        .Protect
        .Name = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd") & " Exchange"
    End With

    UserForm1.Hide
    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

End Sub
```